# How do you access Notebooks stored in Wolfram Cloud offline?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I want to be able to access Notebooks on my laptop when travelling and don't have internet access. Currently, I save a copy to my laptop HHD disc, but this is annoying and I can get caught out by forgetting to save a notebook I need or forgetting to save the latest version.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the cloud syncs well with local files. You need to manually download and save files locally if you plan to go offline.

Answer (score 3):

If  you `NotebookOpen @ CloudObject[ url ]` the opened notebook will be saved to the cloud automatically. So as long as you keep the FrontEnd up it will work.

If you can't keep it open/put to sleep etc you can try this idea:

```
cloudNotebook = CloudDeploy[
  Notebook[{Cell["test", "Section"]}],
  Permissions -> "Public"
];

createTempCloudNotebook @ cloudNotebook
```

`createTempCloudNotebook` fetches and opens a notebook from given link. You will need to pick a file destination when saving for the first time. But aside of that, each time you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> it should check the connection and upload to cloud if possible. It will be manifested with a processing bar on top.

[image]

```
   createTempCloudNotebook // ClearAll;
createTempCloudNotebook[co_CloudObject] := 
 Module[{nb}, nb = NotebookPut@Import[co];
  SetOptions[nb, 
   DockedCells -> {Cell@
      BoxData@ToBoxes@
        DynamicModule[{saved = True, saveNotebook, cloudConnectedQ}, 
         DynamicWrapper[
          Row[{co, 
            Dynamic[
             If[Not@saved, 
              Dynamic@
               ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"], 
              ""]]}, Spacer[20]], If[Not@saved, saveNotebook[]];, 
          TrackedSymbols :> {saved}, SynchronousUpdating -> False], 
         SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
         Initialization :> (cloudConnectedQ[] := 
            Quiet[URLRead[
               HTTPRequest[
                "www.wolframcloud.com", <|"Method" -> "HEAD"|>], 
               "StatusCode"] === 200];

           saveNotebook[] := (If[cloudConnectedQ[], 
              SessionSubmit[CloudDeploy[#, co], 
                 HandlerFunctions -> <|
                   "TaskFinished" :> (saved = True)|>] &@
               EvaluationNotebook[], saved = True]);

           SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
            NotebookEventActions :> {{"MenuCommand", 
                "Save"} :> (saved = False), PassEventsDown -> True, 
              EvaluationOrder -> After}])]}]]
```